# Query to filter rows with same non-primary key value and then exclude records with another null column from result in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample data of table Mytable

```
+----------+--------+----------+
|   BPT    |   BC   |    ST    |
+----------+--------+----------+
| NH       | AB360  | PTOTST   |
| MEMODMHF | AAAAA  | PTOTST   |
| NH       |        | PTOTST   |
| NH       |  ABH6G | PTOTSTCH |
| NH       |        |  PT01    |
| NH       | ABH6G  | PT04     |
| NH       |        | PT04     |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

Filter on BPT column with value NH

```
+------+--------+----------+
| BPT  |   BC   |    ST    |
+------+--------+----------+
| NH   | AB360  | PTOTST   |
| NH   |        | PTOTST   |
| NH   |  ABH6G | PTOTSTCH |
| NH   |        |  PT01    |
| NH   | ABH6G  | PT04     |
| NH   |        | PT04     |
+------+--------+----------+
```

Filter on BC column with value is empty or ABH6G

```
+------+--------+----------+
| BPT  |   BC   |    ST    |
+------+--------+----------+
| NH   |        | PTOTST   |
| NH   |  ABH6G | PTOTSTCH |
| NH   |        |  PT01    |
| NH   | ABH6G  | PT04     |
| NH   |        | PT04     |
+------+--------+----------+
```

For duplicate ST, exclude record with BC as empty

```
+------+--------+----------+
| BPT  |   BC   |    ST    |
+------+--------+----------+
| NH   |        | PTOTST   |
| NH   |  ABH6G | PTOTSTCH |
| NH   |        |  PT01    |
| NH   | ABH6G  | PT04     |
+------+--------+----------+
```

My Sample query mentioned below is not working.How to achieve this.

```
SELECT
  T1.BPT,
  T1.BC,
  T1.ST
FROM Mytable T1,
     Mytable T2
WHERE T1.BEN_PROD_TYP_CD IN ('NH')
AND ((T1.ST = T2.ST
AND T1.BC = 'ABH6G')
OR (T1.ST <> T2.ST
AND (T1.BC = 'ABH6G'
OR T1.BC IS NULL)));
```

Comment: Kindly share your sample data in formatted text, not images. How would you behave if someone shares his answer as image?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Spaces and null are two different things. Are you sure the question means null when it says spaces?

Comment: @zarruq Sorry for images. I not able to frame sql data in stackoverflow in table format.

Comment: @zarruq I have framed table data as you suggested. Now the down vote can be removed

Comment: @Archana: I haven't downvoted your question in first place :-). Its not a norm for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve the result is using `row_number()`:

```
select t.BPT, t.BC, t.ST from
(
select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by st order by BC asc) as rn 
from MyTable t1
where t1.BPT = 'NH'
and (t1.BC = 'ABH6G' or t1.BC is null)
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

**Result:**

```
+-----+-------+----------+
| BPT |  BC   |    ST    |
+-----+-------+----------+
| NH  | NULL  | PTOTST   |
| NH  | ABH6G | PTOTSTCH |
| NH  | NULL  | PT01     |
| NH  | ABH6G | PT04     |
+-----+-------+----------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GYIFG40590)**

Comment: This query worked for me well. Is there any code tip in stackoverflow to format table data

Comment: Yes there are lots of ways. e.g. Format table using [**Format Table**](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/), copy data to SO question and then click `{}` i.e Code Block :-)

Comment: @Archana another fixed table generator is [Ascii Tables](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to be self join for your requirement....

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  T1.BPT,
  T1.BC,
  T1.ST
FROM Mytable T1
WHERE T1.BPT IN ('NH')
AND (T1.BC = 'ABH6G'
OR T1.BC IS NULL);
```

Regards,
Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

Say, for example

```
with
  d as (select bpt, bc, coalesce(bc, '<<spaces>>') bcc, st from MyTable),
  m as (select bcc from d group by bcc having count(*) > 1)
select d.bpt, max(d.bc) bc, d.st
from d, m
where d.bpt = 'NH'
and d.bcc = m.bcc
group by st, bpt
```

[SQL Fiddle for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d52da/5/0)

Comment: ...Thank you for the SQL Fiddle. I have other columns to fetch. But I am getting not a group by expression error.   'with
  d as (select bpt, bc, coalesce(bc, '<<spaces>>') bcc, st, **vcd, vn, vctct** from MyTable),
  m as (select bcc from d group by bcc having count(*) > 1)
select d.bpt, max(d.bc) bc, d.st
from d, m
where d.bpt = 'NH'
and d.bcc = m.bcc
group by st, bpt'

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```
Select * from [Mytable]
Where BPT = 'NH' and BC = 'ABH6G'
union
Select * from [Mytable]
Where BPT = 'NH' and BC = ''
And BPT+BC+ST not in (select BPT + '' + ST from [Mytable]
Where BPT = 'NH' and BC = 'ABH6G')
```

Comment: COALESCE can make the null to empty